# Vector-valued differential forms and cyclic homology

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, noncommutative-geometry

Let $F\rightarrow E \rightarrow M$, where $E$ - smooth flat bundle, $M$ - smooth compact manifold, $F$ - (commutative) algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that local cyclic homology of $\Gamma ^ \infty (M, E)$ coincide with $H^*_{dR}(M,E)$?